# is there a general formula for summation of 2 to i multiply by i?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a formula for $\sum_{i=0}^n a^i*i$? I know there is one for simply  $\sum_{i=0}^n a^i$ and I was digging for properties involving multiplication within the summation but so far there is the constant that you can bring outside of summation. Note n here is finite. If the formula doesn't exist I would like to know how to evaluate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn)

Comment: (Or possibly of some question that specifically asks about the finite sum, but that's the one I know how to find and pretty much all of the answers either explicitly cover the finite sum as well or can be easily modified to do so.)

Comment: I need the one for finite sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elementary way.

Let
$s(n)
=\sum_{i=0}^n a^i
$
and
$t(n)
=\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i
$.

By the usual methods,
we have
$s(n)
=\dfrac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}
$.

Since multiplying
$s(n)$ by $a-1$
makes the result nice,
let's try it with
$t(n)$.

$\begin{array}\\
(a-1)t(n)
&=(a-1)\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i\\
&=a\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i-\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n ia^{i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n ia^i
\qquad\text{since the term with }i=0\text{ is zero}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (i-1)a^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^n ia^i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i-1)a^{i}+na^{n+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n ia^i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} ((i-1)-i)a^{i}+na^{n+1}\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{i}+na^{n+1}\\
&=-(s(n)-1)+na^{n+1}\\
&=na^{n+1}+1-\dfrac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}\\
\text{so}\\
t(n)
&=\dfrac{na^{n+1}+1}{a-1}-\dfrac{a^{n+1}-1}{(a-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(a-1)(na^{n+1}+1)-(a^{n+1}-1)}{(a-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{na^{n+2}-na^{n+1}+a-1-(a^{n+1}-1)}{(a-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{na^{n+2}-(n+1)a^{n+1}+a}{(a-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{a(na^{n+1}-(n+1)a^{n}+1)}{(a-1)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

This reduction in exponent
by multiplying by $a-1$
works for any exponent.

Let
$s_k(n)
=\sum_{i=0}^n i^ka^i
$.

Then,
if $k \ge 2$,
using the binomial theorem,

$\begin{array}\\
(a-1)s_{k}(n)
&=(a-1)\sum_{i=0}^n i^ka^i\\
&=a\sum_{i=0}^n i^ka^i-\sum_{i=0}^n i^ka^i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n i^ka^{i+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n i^ka^i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (i-1)^ka^{i}-\sum_{i=1}^n i^ka^i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (i-1)^ka^{i}+n^{k}a^{n+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n i^ka^i\\
&=n^{k}a^{n+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n (i^k-(i-1)^k)a^i\\
&=n^{k}a^{n+1}-\sum_{i=1}^n (i^k-\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}i^j(-1)^{k-j})a^i\\
&=n^{k}a^{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}i^j(-1)^{k-j})a^i\\
&=n^{k}a^{n+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}\sum_{i=1}^n i^ja^i\\
&=n^{k}a^{n+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}s_j(n)-(-1)^{k}\\
\end{array}
$

That last $(-1)^k$
is due to the
$s_0(n)$
having a constant $1$
while all the others
do not.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $f:a\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^na^i$, compute its derivative and then multiply the result par $a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i & = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=i}^n a^i \\[10pt]
& =\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n a^i - \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} a^i \\[10pt]
& = \frac{n(a^{n+1}-a)}{a-1} - \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a^i-a}{a-1} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{n(a^{n+1}-a)}{a-1} - \frac{a^{n+1}-a}{(a-1)^2} + \frac{an}{a-1} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{na^{n+1}(a-1)-a^{n+1}+a}{(a-1)^2} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{na^{n+2} -(n+1)a^{n+1} +a}{(a-1)^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: On the first line, why does the inner sum go from $i$ to $n$. Shouldn't it go from $1$ to $i$?